# Can get parent object from child object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object

As the title said, I have two class like below:

```
class A {
    constructor() {
       this.a = 1
       this.b = 2
    }
}
Class B extends A {
    constructor() {
       super()
       this.c = 3
    }
}
```

Now, I instance class B

```
const b1 = new B()
```

Can I use some method to get the { a:1, b:2 } from b1. Because I need to post some data through API. But my model is something like class B. but the interface of the API is like class A.
So I just want to get the parent object from the child object.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: if B extends A then .... b1.a would be 1, or did I miss something important?

Comment: *but the interface of the API is like class A* - an aspect of inheritance in OOP is that every single `B` object is an `A` object too, and can be used where `A` objects are expected.

Comment: Practical check: try `console.log(b1 instanceof B, b1 instanceof A);`.

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, you are right. But if the interface of API have a lot of property should be passed. I don't think b1.a  b1.b ...... b1.z is a good code.

Comment: @Courage why is it bad code? This is how JS works, [prototypical inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain).

Comment: @tevemadar I think I can get your point. But if I pass some redundant property to the API. I am afraid that it will cause some confusion for other coder.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I am not sure if I can use this code new A(b), of course, the constructor should be changed in class A. Maybe I can get the result like b1.a and b1.b

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Elegant way to code partially copy objects in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23886484/elegant-way-to-code-partially-copy-objects-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

> Can I use some method to get the `{ a:1, b:2 }` from `b1`?

I interpret this to mean that you want an object with only properties `a` and `b` from `b1`. If that's your meaning, then you can simply pick those properties from `b1` and post the new object:

```js
function pick (obj, keys) {
  const result = {};
  for (const key of keys) result[key] = obj[key];
  return result;
}

class A {
  constructor () {
     this.a = 1;
     this.b = 2;
  }
}

class B extends A {
  constructor () {
     super();
     this.c = 3;
  }
}

const b1 = new B();

// Post this:
const data = pick(b1, ['a', 'b']);

console.log(data); // { a: 1, b: 2 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But what I want is some decent way. Like downcasting or upcasting in JAVA

Comment: @Courage do not expect JavaScript to work like Java, they're not the same. JS doesn't have those concepts. Also have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44291524/javascript-downcasting-object